# I am not getting image link in my firebase database even after following the firebase code example

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The link saves perfectly fine in storage but doesn't save at all in database in any format.

```
  private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage()
{
    Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

    Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime  = currentTime.format(callForTime.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;


    final StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

    filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                SendUserToMainActivity();

                PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
                    {


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();

                StoringTextToFirebaseStorage();

            }
            else
            {
                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code where I should be saving the link, I am using the code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

I believe the issue may be that postimagesreference is also responsible for generating a random id for the image in the storage but I am not sure as I made a copy of the reference called postimagesreference 1 and it still didn't work. Is there anything I'm missing for it to save to database properly? Should I insert the code in a different location?

Here is my entire code if need be:

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private ImageButton SelectPostImage;
private Button AddPostButton;
private EditText PostDescription;

private static final int Gallery_Pick = 1;
private Uri ImageUri;

private StorageReference PostsImagesReference;
//private StorageReference PostsImagesReference1;
private DatabaseReference PostsRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String Description;
private String saveCurrentDate;
private String saveCurrentTime;
private String postRandomName;
private String currentUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    PostsImagesReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    //PostsImagesReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();



    PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

    SelectPostImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select_post_image);
    AddPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_post);
    PostDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_description);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.update_post_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Post");


    SelectPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            OpenGallery();

        }
    });

    AddPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ValidatePostInfo();
        }
    });

}

private void ValidatePostInfo()
{
    Description = PostDescription.getText().toString();

    if(ImageUri == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Description))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please say something about your image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Post Uploading");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please Wait");
        loadingBar.show();
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        StoringImageToFirebaseStorage();

    }
}

private void StoringTextToFirebaseStorage()
{

    Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

    Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime  = currentTime.format(callForDate.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;


    HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
    postsMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
    postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
    postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
    postsMap.put("description", Description);
    postsMap.put("image", PostsImagesReference);

    PostsRef.child(currentUserID + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {

                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }

            });


}


private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage()
{
    Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

    Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime  = currentTime.format(callForTime.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;


    final StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

    filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                SendUserToMainActivity();

                PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
                    {


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();

                StoringTextToFirebaseStorage();

            }
            else
            {
                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}





private void OpenGallery()
{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
}






@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        ImageUri = data.getData();
        SelectPostImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        SendUserToMainActivity();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private void SendUserToMainActivity()
{
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

}

My dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within

```
 @Override

            public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
            {
                     String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                     DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                     db.child("users").child("pics").setValue(downloadUrl);

            }
```

The `uri.toString();` will be your download url :)

```
private void StoringTextToFirebaseStorage(Uri downloadUrl)
{

    Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

    Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime  = currentTime.format(callForDate.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;


    HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
    postsMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
    postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
    postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
    postsMap.put("description", Description);
    postsMap.put("image", downloadUrl.toString());

    PostsRef.child(currentUserID + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {

                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }

            });


}


private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage()
{
    Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

    Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime  = currentTime.format(callForTime.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;


    final StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

    filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                SendUserToMainActivity();

                PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
                    {
                      StoringTextToFirebaseStorage(uri);


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();


            }
            else
            {
                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the hashmap in storingtexttofirebase do I insert downloadUrl beside "image" or postsimagesreference beside "image"?

Comment: downloadUrl and you'll need to use a library such as Glide / Picasso to load the URL

If my answer solved the problem for you please click the green tick next to the answer :)

Comment: It actually created the map in the database but the "image" is missing for some reason. Is the code that gets the image link meant to go into storingtexttofirebase instead of storingimagetofirebase? Or could it be that I put in the wrong children in the code that you gave me, what should the children be in relation to my code? I have "Posts" first and "image" as the second one.

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect how you would store the downloadUrl of an image using your methods

Comment: If you found my answer correct can i ask you to click the tick on the left hand side of the answer to say it's correct.  For more information on what to do when someone answers your question click here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have used the exact same code as you have given me and it doesn't save any info into the database, is it possible that I may be missing something like a dependency?
I will edit my post to show them.

Comment: I am now getting a storageexception error, what could be the cause?

Comment: Sorry billy i had to go to work, can you copy the storage exception code.

Comment: I suspect its because you have a space in your storage reference it should be .child("PostImages")

Comment: It is okay now, I got it to work. PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener should've been filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener it saves the link to the database now, thanks so much.

Comment: No problem Steve, can you mark my answer as correct please.